# Magento2 Checkout cart automatically updates when qty changes with ajax

Tags: checkout, cart, upgrade, ajax

Magento2 checkout cart page

Please ensure when quantities are changed that the cart automatically updates. Some customers might change the quantity and if they dont click update cart they might move on to checkout how their cart updates automatically when quantity is changed.

Thank you,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my site, I installed : [AJAX Shopping Cart Update](https://marketplace.magento.com/rltsquare-ajax-shopping-cart-update.html). It's free module.